# A php preg_replace pattern [[ and ]]

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I couldn't seem to make my code work.

Consider a string

```
$string = "the [[quick [[brown]] fox [jumps]] over the]] lazy dog";
```

I want to remove all words in [[ ]] thus giving me a result "the lazy dog".

using `preg_replace('/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/s', '' ,$string)` will give me a result:

> the ]] lazy dog

Which is wrong. Does anyone have a work around with this?

Comment: Does it have to be with a regex or are you open to alternate methods?

Comment: it would be nice if there is an alternate method which is faster than regex.

Answer (score 1):

It will be difficult doing it with regex.  I'd suggest just doing it by hand.

```
function replace_brackets($source) {
    $result = '';
    $brackets = 0;
    foreach (preg_split('/(\[\[|\]\])/', $source, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) as $segment) {
        if ($segment == '[[') {
            $brackets++;
        } else if ($segment == ']]') {
            $brackets--;
        } else if ($brackets == 0) {
            $result .= $segment;
        }
   }

   return $result;
}

echo replace_brackets("the [[quick [[brown]] fox [jumps]] over the]] lazy dog [[ta]] da\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/\[\[.*\]\]/s', '' ,$string)
```

Comment: This expression is greedy, so it doesn't work for something like: `"the [[quick [[brown]] fox [jumps]] over the]] lazy dog [[also this]]"`

Comment: That may work for his example string, but what about `[[the [[quick]] ]] brown [[fox]]`?  It's going to replace too much.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\[\[(?:(?:\[\[.*?\]\]|.)*?)\]\]/s
```

The operative difference is `(?:\[\[.*?\]\]|.)*?`.  Instead of your `.*?`, it first attempts to match a bracketed string, then if that fails, it tries `.`.

Comment: this only works up to 2 level how about `the [[quick [[brown]] fox [[jumps [[another inside]] ]] over the]] lazy dog`

Comment: Regex is insanely impressive in that it looks like you were trying to clean your keyboard but that actually does stuff.

Comment: @Ralpu, regex isn't good for recursive stuff.  If you want additional levels, you'll probably have to write it in php... unless you want to move to .net.  The .net regex implementation has additional 'depth' capabilities that can be used to solve this problem.